# Azure Log Analytics won't find my Docker Container log lines

Tags: azure, docker, nlog, azure-log-analytics

I have an App Service in Azure which runs a Docker Container contained in the Azure Container Registry. I can run the container locally using Docker for Windows. I've set it up
using NLog in a .NET Core 5.0 environment. It's a Rest API using Swagger. I can open up a CLI to my running container, see and read my logfile in /var/log. The container uses
a Linux OS. I've followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs
I'm not getting any lines when trying to select log-entries in Azure "ProjectName-Monitor | Logs" using:
company_projectname_logs_CL;
It's set up like this:
Filebased   Linux   /var/log/*

In an endpoint of my API I output the first 20 loglines of my log so I know the log exists in the Azure App Service Container. These are some of them

```
2021-07-09 14:47:52.8651|35|WARN|Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager|No XML encryptor configured. Key {255555555-ccccc-4444-99999-aaaaaaaaaaaa} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form. 
2021-07-09 14:47:53.0028||INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Now listening on: http://[::]:80 
2021-07-09 14:47:53.0028||INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. 
2021-07-09 14:47:53.0028||INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Hosting environment: Production 
2021-07-09 14:47:53.0028||INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Content root path: /app 
2021-07-09 14:47:53.3533|3|WARN|Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware|Failed to determine the https port for redirect. 
2021-07-09 14:49:34.4260||DEBUG|CompanyName.Logging.Logger|init main function 
2021-07-09 14:49:34.4321||DEBUG|CompanyName.Logging.Logger|application: ProjectName, appId: 2, orderNumber: 2000000, sessionId: abc-123-def-456, Msg: Hej!!! 
2021-07-09 14:49:34.4321||INFO|CompanyName.Logging.Logger|application: ProjectName, appId: 2, orderNumber: 2000000, sessionId: abc-123-def-456, Msg: Hej!!! 
2021-07-09 14:49:34.4321||ERROR|CompanyName.Logging.Logger|application: ProjectName, appId: 2, orderNumber: 2000000, sessionId: abc-123-def-456, Msg: Hej!!! 
2021-07-09 14:49:34.4321||WARN|CompanyName.Logging.Logger|application: ProjectName, appId: 2, orderNumber: 2000000, sessionId: abc-123-def-456, Msg: Hej!!! 
2021-07-09 14:49:34.4336||DEBUG|CompanyName.Logging.Logger|application: ProjectName, appId: 3, orderNumber: 1234567, sessionId: abc-123-def-456, Msg: Hei!!! 
2021-07-09 14:49:34.4336||WARN|CompanyName.Logging.Logger|application: ProjectName, appId: 4, orderNumber: 1999999, sessionId: abc-123-def-456, Msg: Kiitos!!! 
2021-07-09 14:49:34.4336||INFO|CompanyName.Logging.Logger|application: ProjectName, appId: 5, orderNumber: 1555555, sessionId: abc-123-def-456, Msg: Haj!!! 
2021-07-09 14:49:34.4336||ERROR|CompanyName.Logging.Logger|application: ProjectName, appId: 17, orderNumber: 1888888, sessionId: abc-123-def-456, Msg: Tschüß!!! 
2021-07-09 14:49:38.4737||DEBUG|CompanyName.Logging.Logger|init main function 
2021-07-09 14:49:38.4737||DEBUG|CompanyName.Logging.Logger|application: ProjectName, appId: 2, orderNumber: 2000000, sessionId: abc-123-def-456, Msg: Hej!!! 
2021-07-09 14:49:38.4777||INFO|CompanyName.Logging.Logger|application: ProjectName, appId: 2, orderNumber: 2000000, sessionId: abc-123-def-456, Msg: Hej!!! 
2021-07-09 14:49:38.4777||ERROR|CompanyName.Logging.Logger|application: ProjectName, appId: 2, orderNumber: 2000000, sessionId: abc-123-def-456, Msg: Hej!!!
```

I think the encoding is UTF-8

The nlog.config file is listed below. Though NLog is not the problem. It works and produces log-files in the /var/log/ folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true" internalLogLevel="info" internalLogFile="internalLog.txt">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
  </extensions>
  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <variable name="logDir" value="/var/log"/>
  <targets>
    <!-- write to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="alldata" fileName="${logDir}/companyname-projectname-${shortdate}.log" layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
    <!-- another file log. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="otherFile-web" fileName="${logDir}/companyname-projectname-other-${shortdate}.log" layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
  </targets>
  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="alldata" />
    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Info" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="otherFile-web" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Can you update the question to also include the NLog configuration (ex. nlog.config) ? Have you tried to use `filename="${environment:HOME:cached=true}/logfiles/application/app-${shortdate}-${processid}.txt"` for the NLog FileTarget ?

Comment: I added nlog.config

Comment: When reading the manual, then the filename must match the pattern `"log*.txt"`. Maybe try changing to `fileName="${logDir}/log-companyname-projectname-${shortdate}.txt"`

Comment: I changed the names. Still no log lines. This is the filter: /var/log/log*.txt. The filename is log-companyname-projectname-2021-07-15.txt. Do I have to have them in /var/log/audit/log*.txt? Do you have to wait? You still should be able to list log lines even though they're inside a container?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs